# cx_Oracle.SessionPool with connection String

Tags: python, oracle

How to connect `cx_Oracle.SessionPool` with only connection string in Python? Currently I have been connecting with:

```
self.mypool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(user=self.usr, password=self.pwd, dsn=self.dsn, min=1, max=2, increment=1)
```

Due to the oracle wallet change, I have only the connection string.

Answer (score 3):

I spend two days to find the solution.

```
cx_Oracle.SessionPool(dsn='ORCL', min=1, max=20, increment=1, threaded=True, externalauth=True,homogeneous=False,user='',password='')
```

**From cx_Oracle documentation**

*Add support for externally identified users; to use this feature leave the username and password fields empty
when connecting*

- `externalauth=True` allows to use oracle wallet.
- `homogeneous=False` allows to use different authentication in the pool

**dsn** should be set up in `tnsnames.ora`

e.g.

```
ORCL=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xx.xx.xx.xx)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))
```